# Passing variables between different instances

Tags: java, collections

The `getDistance()` function in the below code is not working properly. The different instances do not pass the distance value correctly. The correct values are as follows:  `d1 = 0` , `d2 = 1`, `d3 = 2`.
What is the problem in my code?

```
 package javaapplication28;

public class JavaApplication28 {
    public interface State {
        public double getDistance();
        public State getParent();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abstract class AbstractState implements
                State {
            private State parent = null;
            protected double distance = 0;

            public AbstractState(State parent) {
                this.parent = parent;
                this.distance = parent.getDistance() + 1;
            }
        }

        class ThisState extends AbstractState {
            State parent;
            public ThisState(State parent) {
                super(parent);
            }


            public State getParent() {
                return parent;
            }

            public double getDistance() {
                return distance;
            }
        }
        ThisState TS1 = new ThisState(null);
        ThisState TS2 = new ThisState(TS1);
        ThisState TS3 = new ThisState(TS2);

        int d1 = TS1.getDistance();
        int d2 = TS2.getDistance();
        int d3 = TS3.getDistance();
    }
}
```

Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: What do you think `double` is? What do you think `int` is? Do you know what a return type is?

Comment: This is a part of sample code for the Farmer-Wolf-Goat-Cabbage problem.

Comment: Correctly d1, d2, d3 are double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (parent != null) { // Hello !?
    this.distance = parent.getDistance() + 1;
}
```

---

Full code:

```
public class Application4995 {

    public interface State {
        public double getDistance();
        public State getParent();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       abstract class AbstractState implements State {
            private State parent = null;
            protected double distance = 0;

            public AbstractState(State parent) {
                this.parent = parent;
                if (parent != null) { // Hello !?
                    this.distance = parent.getDistance() + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        class ThisState extends AbstractState {
            State parent;
            public ThisState(State parent) {
                super(parent);
            }


            public State getParent() {
                return parent;
            }

            public double getDistance() {
                return distance;
            }
        }
        ThisState TS1 = new ThisState(null);
        ThisState TS2 = new ThisState(TS1);
        ThisState TS3 = new ThisState(TS2);

        double d1 = TS1.getDistance(); // or int d1 = (int) TS1.getDistance();
        double d2 = TS2.getDistance(); // or int d2 = (int) TS2.getDistance();
        double d3 = TS3.getDistance(); // or int d3 = (int) TS3.getDistance();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you run this:

```
ThisState TS1 = new ThisState(null);
```

you will get to this constructor with `parent` set to `null`:

```
public AbstractState(State parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
  this.distance = parent.getDistance() + 1;
}
```

which will lead to null pointer exception in the second line of the constructor.

what you need to do is set distance to `parent.getDistance() + 1` only if parent is not null